# try catch block not catching limit exception after query

Tags: apex, exception, try-catch

I have a SOQL query call inside a try catch block, because I want to catch if a LimitException is thrown, but for some reason, when the exception is thrown after the query,the aura handled exception is not thrown and in my LWC, I get the original exception.

```
List<Producto__c> productos = new List<Producto__c>();
    try{
        productos = Database.query(queryProducto + getQueryOrder() + qryLimit);
    }catch(LimitException e){
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'CATCH');
        throw new AuraHandledException('La busqueda arrojó demasiados registros. Aplique más filtros');
    }
```

[image]

As you can see, the query IS  being executed after the exception (it seems at least), but when checking the debug logs, we never see the debug message inside the catch block.

[image]

Is it a bug? Or the exception is being thrown before the query or something like that... This never happened to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions thrown because you've exceeded a governor limit are un-catchable.

They will *always* cause your code to stop executing at the point where the limit is exceeded. That's how Salesforce is able to enforce governor limits.

Instead of trying to catch exceptions, it's up to us to design and write our code in a way that is unlikely to run into the limits or to check the various items that the `Limits` class provides to prevent executing something that would put you over a limit.

For some things, like the number of SOQL queries, it's easy to tell when you're about to go over the limit, so something like

```java
if(Limits.getQueries() < Limits.getLimitQuery()){
    // safe to run another query
}
```

will work

For other things, like the number of query rows, it's harder to tell if you're going to exceed the limit. In those cases, it can be helpful to build in a safety threshold

```java
if(Limits.getQueryRows() < Limits.getLimitQueryRows() * 0.9){
    // it's probably safe to run a query
    // ...as long as you think it won't return more than 5,000 (50,000 * 0.1) rows
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, thats exactly the case. my mistake for not checking the documentation. The thing is, my apex method has a very complex query system, with several sub-queries (which count for the rows limit) involving several filters sent from the client, so working the code out to never reach the governor limits would be very time consuming. Our idea was to , in the case the limits where reached, send a custom excpetion that tells the user to apply more filters to reduce the scope of the search. I'll just make a workaround on my LWC directly.